# WooCommerce customized email only for processing and completed orders

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

I am using a plugin to send custom referral codes in the email orders but now I found that every order email has the code inserted.

```
function gens_raf_customer_email( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text ) {
$user_id = ( version_compare( WC_VERSION, '2.7', '<' ) ) ? $order->customer_user : $order->get_customer_id();
if( ! empty( $user_id ) && ( get_user_meta($user_id, "gens_referral_id", true) ) != '' ){
    $code = get_user_meta($user_id, "gens_referral_id", true);
} else {
    $code = ( version_compare( WC_VERSION, '2.7', '<' ) ) ? $order->billing_email : $order->get_billing_email();
}

if( $plain_text ){
    _e('Your referral code is: ','gens-raf') . $code;
} else {
    echo '<p style="text-align:center;margin-top:10px;">Your referral code is: ' .get_home_url() .'?raf='. $code . '</p>';
}
```

}
add_action('woocommerce_email_customer_details', 'gens_raf_customer_email', 30, 3 );

I was messing around with

```
if ( $email->id == 'customer_completed_order' )
```

But gave me error from the php code builder. The main issue is to send that email only to completed and/or processing orders instead of refunded, cancelled and so on.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the error because you didn't add the fourth **`$email`** argument available to the `woocommerce_email_customer_details` hook.

> The content will only be displayed in the **Completed order** and
> **Processing order** templates.

Try this:

```
add_action('woocommerce_email_customer_details', 'gens_raf_customer_email', 30, 4 );
function gens_raf_customer_email( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {

    if ( $email->id == 'customer_completed_order' || $email->id == 'customer_processing_order' ) {
        $user_id = ( version_compare( WC_VERSION, '2.7', '<' ) ) ? $order->customer_user : $order->get_customer_id();
        if( ! empty( $user_id ) && ( get_user_meta($user_id, "gens_referral_id", true) ) != '' ){
            $code = get_user_meta($user_id, "gens_referral_id", true);
        } else {
            $code = ( version_compare( WC_VERSION, '2.7', '<' ) ) ? $order->billing_email : $order->get_billing_email();
        }
    
        if( $plain_text ){
            _e('Your referral code is: ','gens-raf') . $code;
        } else {
            echo '<p style="text-align:center;margin-top:10px;">Your referral code is: ' .get_home_url() .'?raf='. $code . '</p>';
        }  
    }
    
}
```

*The code has been tested and works.*

Comment: Vincenzo it did work.. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The variable `$email` is the 4th missing argument from your hooked function, that you need to target specific email notifications.

Use instead *(for woocommerce 3 and above)*:

```
add_action('woocommerce_email_customer_details', 'gens_raf_customer_email', 100, 4 );
function gens_raf_customer_email( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
    // Target specific notifications: Customer processing and completed orders
    if ( in_array( $email->id, ['customer_processing_order', 'customer_completed_order'] ) ) {
        $gens_raf = get_user_meta( $order->get_user_id(), "gens_referral_id", true );
        $code     = empty( $gens_raf ) ? $order->get_billing_email() : $gens_raf;

        if( $plain_text ){
            printf( __('Your referral code is: %s', 'gens-raf'), $code );
        } else {
            $output = sprintf( __("Your referral code is: %s", "gens-raf"), get_home_url() .'?raf='. $code );
            echo '<p style="text-align:center;margin-top:10px;">' . $output . '</p>';
        }  
    }  
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should works.